# Cauchy estimate application and polynomial degree

Tags: complex-analysis

The Cauchy estimate is as follows:

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of the closed ball $B(\alpha,r)$
and suppose
$$
M(\alpha,r) = \max_{|z-\alpha|=r}|f(z)|,
$$
then
$$
|f^{(n)}(\alpha)| \le \frac{n! M(\alpha,r)}{r^{n}}.
$$

Using the Cauchy estimate,
I want to prove the following proposition:
if an entire function $f$ satisfies
$$
\lim_{r \longrightarrow \infty}
\max_{|z|\le r} \frac{|f(z)|}{r^{n+1}} =0,
$$
then
$$
f^{(n+1)}(z) = 0.
$$

I can prove $f^{(n+1)}(0)=0$ but I can't find a way to prove the proposition for all $z$.
Could someone help me, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is entire, it can be written as a power series around $z = 0$. In particular, notice that:
$$|f^{(m)}(0)| \leq \frac{m! \sup_{|z| \leq r} |f(z)|}{r^m}$$
This is certainly true for every $r > 0$. In particular, this implies that $f^{(m)}(0) = 0$ for all $m > n$ and this holds due to the limit you are given. But this means that $f$ must just be a polynomial of degree at most $n$ and we're done.